# join based on one of multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm using SQL Server.

table1

```
comment_no   comment 
1            excellent 
2            ok
3            acceptable
```

table2

```
name    service_comment   quality_comment   quantity_comment 
shop1   0                 0                 1
shop2   0                 2                 0
shop3   1                 0                 0
```

desired result

```
name    service_comment   quality_comment   quantity_comment   comment 
shop1   0                 0                 1                  excellent 
shop2   0                 2                 0                  good
shop3   1                 0                 0                  excellent
```

How can I join the two tables to get this result?

Comment: What if the three values are 1, 2 ,3? what if it was 3, 2, 1?

Comment: For me the reason you are struggling with this query is because your table design is flawed. Your table2 should have a column indicating which type of comment it is.

Answer (score 2):

For the data you have presented, you can use `left join` and coalesce:

```
select t1.*,
       coalesce(t2s.comment, t2ql.comment, t2qn.comment) as comment
from t1 left join
     t2 t2s
     on t1.service_comment = t2s.comment_no left join
     t2 t2ql
     on t1.quality_comment = t2ql.comment_no left join
     t2 t2qn
     on t1.quantity_comment = t2qn.comment_no;
```

If you can have multiple comments, then you might prefer:

```
select t1.*,
       trim('; ' from (coalesce('; ' + t2s.comment, '') + 
                      (coalesce('; ' + t2ql.comment, '') +
                      (coalesce('; ' + t2qn.comment, '')
                     )
       ) as comment
from t1 left join
     t2 t2s
     on t1.service_comment = t2s.comment_no left join
     t2 t2ql
     on t1.quality_comment = t2ql.comment_no left join
     t2 t2qn
     on t1.quantity_comment = t2qn.comment_no;
```